# Loading Image from Google Drive into HTML Canvas Causes Canvas to be Tainted

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, google-drive-api

When I load an IMage into a canvas from Google Drive like so:

```
var folderID = "0B5Oh0J4bIygXUVNCa3JOVlc1WU0";
var sprt = new Image();
sprt.src = 'https://googledrive.com/host/' + folderID + '/ground1.png';
```

When I then try to render this Image on the Canvas, I get an error message saying that the canvas has been tainted due to a Cross Origin Error. Is there a way to enable me to load images from Google Drive?

I have set the following, but it sill does not work:

```
sprt.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
```

The folder that contains the file is set to Public Access as well.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

Comment: If you're going to authorize users and then load images from their bucket, you better be using a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a CORS configuration on the bucket that contains all the origins you wish to share the bucket with, and the request methods that you want to allow on that bucket.

> You must have a server hosting images with the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.  Adding crossOrigin attribute makes a request header.

Here is the sample [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image#Example_Storing_an_image_from_a_foreign_origin).

Comment: You may try this [Drive Platform Example Apps](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/examples/) and check for the **[Uploading](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) and [downloading](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) files using CORS** example.